# Error: Audio playback was aborted HTML

Tags: java, html, servlets, jdbc

Here is my servlet., I am able to upload songs bur unable to play it on on my webpage. Everything seems right. I donno where i had gone wrong. src i had referred to a link is correct., i mean path is correct.But where i had gone wrong i dunno.

[image: This is the error Im getting]

Here is My Servlet PlaySinger.java

```
package com.ea.servlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class PlaySinger extends HttpServlet
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Statement st;
public ResultSet rs;
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public PlaySinger() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{

        //loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //creating connection with the database 
          Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EATWO","root","");
          PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            HttpSession h=request.getSession();
            String film=request.getParameter("film");
            String uname=request.getParameter("userID");             

         st = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from eatwo.vocal where userID='"+uname+"'");
         out.println("<html><head>"
                    + "<title>Listen</title>"
                    //+ "<link rel='stylesheet' href='table2.css' type='text/css' media='screen' title='no title' charset='utf-8'/>"
                    +  "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style4.css' type='text/css' media='screen' title='no title' charset='utf-8'/>"
                    + "</head>" 
                    + "<body background='musicOne.jpg'>");  
         out.println("<table width='358' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' class='table'>");
         out.println("<tr><td><p id='head'>Songs Uploaded</p></td></tr>");
         out.println("<tr><td><br></td></tr>");
            while(rs.next())
            {                   
                        //out.println("<tr><td>'"+h.getAttribute("phno1")+"'</tr></td>");
                        File f = new File(rs.getString(4));
                        //C:\wamp\www\EHSAUDIO
                        String src1 = "c:\\wamp\\www\\EHSAUDIO\\"+f.getName();
                        String audformat = f.getName();

                        if(audformat.contains("mp3"))
                        {
                            audformat = "audio/mpeg";
                        }
                        else
                            if(audformat.contains("ogg"))
                            {
                                audformat = "audio/ogg";
                            }
                        else
                            if(audformat.contains("wav"))
                                {
                                    audformat = "audio/wav";
                                }
                            else
                                if(audformat.contains(""))
                                {
                                    audformat="";
                                }

                        //out.println(src1 + ""+ audformat);
                        System.out.println("source "+src1+" Audio Format "+audformat);

    out.println("<tr><td><audio controls autoplay><source src=\""+src1+"\" type=\""+audformat+"\"> </audio><br><br><br>")   ;

            }
             out.println("<tr><td><a href='logout.html'>LOGOUT</a></td></tr>");
             System.out.println("uname is"+uname);
            // out.println("<tr><td><a href='prod1?username="+uname+"'>Contact This Singer</a></td></tr>");
             out.println("</table>");   

                    out.println( "</body></html>");
                    out.println("");                    


     }
catch(Exception e3)
 {
     e3.printStackTrace();
}
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer myself
I just used 
src1="http://localhost/EHSAUDIO/"+f.getName()";
instead of considering path.
Thank You